# Literate Emacs Configuration Exclusion

Tags: init-file, org-babel

When using literate configuration, is there a way to exclude code blocks?

Maybe tag the babel blocks to include or exclude?

Any great ideas?;)

Comment: A `:tangle no` header prevents the code block from being tangled - in fact, that's the default: you have to take explicit action to include the block in the tangled file. Is that what you want? If not, can you explain what you mean by `literate configuration`?

Comment: Hmm, I've based my config on this way to do it and it includes all code blocks: https://github.com/mrvdb/emacs-config

Comment: ok, :tangle no works great;) , but what if I want to just type :tangle yes when I want something included? Where is it set that it's default everything included?;)

Comment: Why don't you add a small example in the question that does not work the way you expect it to?

Comment: By default, nothing is included (i.e. `:tangle no` is the default. If you want to include something in the tangled file, you have to add a `:tangle yes` or `:tangle /path/to/tangled/file` header.

Comment: if you look at this file, which I use, it doesn't use this :tangle yes anywhere: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrvdb/emacs-config/master/mrb.org

Comment: And the problem is ...?

Comment: @NickD You should post your first comment as the answer and OP should accept it. We can then move on to any other issues in a new question.

Comment: @NickD you said that nothing is included by default, but the config I've posted shows that everything is included by default. I don't see in this config that I've posted how it makes it the inverse.

Comment: Let me repeat: Why don't you add a small example in the question that does not work the way you expect it to? An example of 4000 lines does not qualify as "small".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block won't be excluded:

```
*** CUA mode
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (cua-mode t)
#+end_src
```

This block will be excluded because it has the `COMMENT` state, which has been added with `C-c ;` (`C-c ;` runs the command `org-toggle-comment`):

```
*** COMMENT Highlighting syntax in code blocks
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (setq org-src-fontify-natively t)
#+end_src
```

Answer (score 0):

[Not an answer, but we are talking at cross purposes in the comments, so maybe this will help]

Here's a small example (in a file called `foo500.org`):

```el
* foo

#+begin_src elisp
  (princ "Hello world")
#+end_src
```

Trying to tangle this with `C-c C-v C-t` produces the message `Tangled 0 code blocks from foo500.org`.

If I change the code block to this:

```el
* foo

#+begin_src elisp :tangle yes
  (princ "Hello world")
#+end_src
```

then tangling with `C-c C-v C-t` produces the message `Tangled 1 code block from foo500.org` *and* there is now a file `foo500.el` containing
this:

```el
(princ "Hello world")
```

That's what I said in the comments and that's what I've *shown* above.

If this works the same way for you, then what happens with your 4000-line file is *irrelevant*: you have made a wrong diagnosis of the problem and me looking at it is not going to help unless I try it out - something which I'm not going to do, since I don't have the time.

If it does *not* work the same way for you, then I'm willing to look a little further, but *you* have to do the work to narrow it down.

I hope that helps.